# Monte Carlo Greeks for Fixed Strike Asian Call

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, greeks, asian-option

I am interested in pricing an European-style fixed strike asian call with payoff $\max(A(S)-K;0)$, where $A(S)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nS(t_i)$ is a discrete arithmetic average and $K$ is the strike price.

Assuming an arbitrage-free and complete market, the fundamental theorem of asset pricing tells us  that the arbitrage-free price at time $t=0$ is given by:
$$
V(0)=E^{\mathbb{Q}}(\max(A(S)-K) \vert {\cal F}_0 )
$$
I have no idea whether there exists an analytic solution or not, so I decided to use MC by implementing the following pseudo-code in python (I omit the code so as not to prolong the question).

Under the Black-Scholes assumptions, let $m$ be the number of paths, $n$ be the number of intervals per path and $\delta t= \frac{T}{n}$, then:

1. Simulate geometric brownian motion under $\mathbb{Q}$ measure $S_i(t+1)=S_i(t) \exp \left(\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)\delta t+\sigma \sqrt{\delta t}Z_t\right)$ where $Z_t \sim{\cal N}(0,1)$ for $i \in [1,m]$ and $t \in [0,n]$.
2. Calculate option payoff $X_i=\max(A_i(S_i)-K)$ and set $V_i(0,K,T,\sigma,r,S(0))=e^{-rT}X_i$
3. Calculate sample average $V(0,K,T,\sigma,r,S(0))=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m V_i(0,K,T,\sigma,r,S(0))$

However, when I want to calculate higher order greeks, especially those involving mixed derivatives, things get messy because I have to repeat this process several times and change the parameters slightly. For instance, calculating DdeltaDvol using finite differences yields:

\begin{align*}
DdeltaDvol &= \frac{1}{4 \Delta S \Delta \sigma} [V(0,K,T,\sigma+\Delta \sigma,r,S(0)+\Delta S)-V(0,K,T,\sigma-\Delta \sigma,r,S(0)+\Delta S) \\
&\quad -V(0,K,T,\sigma+\Delta \sigma,r,S(0)-\Delta S)+V(0,K,T,\sigma-\Delta \sigma,r,S(0)-\Delta S)]
\end{align*}
The fact that I have to simulate the whole asset path thousands of times and a with small $\delta t$ makes the whole approach computationally intensive.

Does anyone know an alternative approach which is not so computationally intensive ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you fix the [RNG‘s seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed)? Usually, when numerically computing derivatives under MC, you’d ‚re-use‘ the random variables used in your Brownian motion.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I fix the seed and then re use the variabels. But I don’t see an easy way to calculate $V(0,\sigma + \Delta \sigma,S(0)+\Delta S)$ from $ V(0,\sigma, S(0))$ in a vectorized version, so I have to re-run the loops.

Comment: Depending on your chosen language, you should be perfectly able to vectorise the equations. Could you provide the relevant portions of your code?